# JTable does not paints after menu action

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a question regarding JTable. This code was mixed of java tutorials. I just wanted to make it quick. I need to draw a sample table after hitting menu action. For example this code is paiting table after hitting file-> load. Problem is: table is drawing after hitting action and resizing window. It needs to work without touching size of window. Probably I would need some refresh/repaint on some components. I tried few ways (invoke .repaint() on many swing objects) but I didn't find any solution. Thanks for any help.

```
package pl.edu.pb.szkszym.view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Start extends JFrame {
    private JTable table;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Start frame = new Start();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Start() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load");
        mntmLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("c files", "c");
                fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Open file");

                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println(file);
                    table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(new String[] { "col1",
                            "col2" }, new Object[][] {
                            { "Kathy", new Integer(5) },
                            { "John", "Doe" },
                            { new Integer(2),
                                    new Boolean(false) } }));
                    Container container = getContentPane();
                    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    container.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                    container.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);


                }
            }

        });

        mnFile.add(mntmLoad);

    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames;
        private Object[][] data;

        public MyTableModel(String[] columns, Object[][] data) {
            this.columnNames = columns;
            this.data = data;
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            // Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            // no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can
         * change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container needs to be revalidated and repainted after adding the `JTable` component

```
container.revalidate();
container.repaint();
```

Comment: Wow :) Simple and easy :) Thank You very much!